# Laravel 5.5 Eloquent - Optionally chain where statements

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want the following to happen - search by fields if fields are different from "all". Something like this:

// If $request['field'] != 'all' add query

```
if(isset($request['types'])) {
    $query = Offer::whereHas('types', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $typeArray = $request->get('types'); 
        $query->whereIn('type', $typeArray);
    });
}

if ($request['country'] != 'all') {
   query->where('country_id', $country);
}
```

At the end I want to order and paginate the results like so:

```
$offers = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
```

Is there any way to achieve this? If my question isn't clear enough tell me and I will edit it and try to explain better.

Comment: You want to build an query builder with the conditions of your request? I'm right?

Comment: @AndersonAndrade Correct. I want to build my query according to the selected fields by the user.

Comment: Could you place `if ($request['country']...` inside of that anonymous function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
You can use eloquent when method to check conditions and append query. in when method you can check your conditions.

Offer::when(isset($request['types']), function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('types', function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('type', request()->get('types'));
    });
})
->when(request()->country != 'all', function($query) {
    $query->where('country_id', request()->country);
})
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: This is imo the better way to go for simple things like this. when is nice and clean for such things. PS you did forget the orderBy and paginate in your answer ;) PPS I will try an edit from your answer, how I understand the question

Comment: @pravindabhi I find your solution the most elegant and suitable for my needs. Marked your answer as correct! Could you upvote my question? Thanks for the help, Pravin!

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
<?php

$query = Offer::where(function($q) use ($request){
    if ( !empty($request['country']) && is_numeric($request['country']) ) {
        $query->where('country_id', $request['country']);
    }

    if( !empty($request['types']) && is_array($request['types']) ) {
        $q->whereHas('types', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $typeArray = $request->get('types'); 
            $q->whereIn('type', $typeArray);
        });
    }
});


$offers = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);
```

Comment: I think it works! Thanks a lot Anderson! I upvoted your answer. I will test it some more and mark your answer as correct if everything is fine.

Comment: Yes it worked. However I find @pravindabhi 's solution more elegant and suitable. Thanks for the help!